# Linux mint 17 battery information inconsistent

Tags: battery

The battery (time remaining) information shown by Linux Mint 17 on my [Asus Zenbook UX32LA](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/UX32LA/) is inconsistent. When I unplug it from the AC power (99% charged), it says 4:55h, after 1 min it shows 7:15h, at 75% it shows 6:25h and then after 1 min it shows 3:30h. The ASUS website states it should be "ok" to work for up to 7-8h.

How can I make the time reported consistent? Some suggestions/solutions ?

**ASUS ZenBook UX32LA-R3086H**

TB - taskbar battery information; 
TRB - terminal battery information through acpi -b

Better example: I checked now at 71% and **TB** is was 5:30h, with **TRB** shows 5:16h, now at 70% it shows **TB** shows 6:15h and at **TRB** shows 5:55:50h

Very awkward!

Comment: I trimmed the irrelevant details about the various issues you've already solved and provided a link to your laptop's model. Please check that I've given the right model (there is no UX32L, only UX32LA and UX32LR). Also, please [edit] and clarify where this remaining time is reported and whether you get the same answer if you open a terminal and run `acpi -b`. Finally, you should know that since this kind of information depends on the system communicating with the battery correctly, it is often problematic on Linux since vendors don't always provide Linux-specific software for this.

Comment: Really sounds like a driver bug.  It's getting the max duration from the hardware and obviously it is getting it wrong and inconsistently.  If the % seems sane, just pay attention to that and ignore the time.

Comment: But how should I guess +- when is the battery gone ?